# How to bind object property to datasource in DropDownList without using ViewData

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a DropDownList column in my kendo Grid. I want to change my ViewData["genres"] in DataSource to GenreViewModel property "AllGenres". How can I do that? Don't forget that I use js version of Grid(not mvc).

I think it should looks like:

```
dataSource: @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize("AllGenres"))
```

or

```
dataSource: "AllGenres"
```

against of:

```
dataSource: @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["genres"]))
```

**My DropDownList:**

```
function genreDropDownEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required name="' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataTextField: "GenreName",
            dataValueField: "GenreId",
            dataSource: @Html.Raw(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["genres"]))               
});
<script type="text/kendo" id="genresTemplate">
    #if(data.Genre != null)
    { #

    #: Genre.GenreName #

    # } #
```

**My GenreViewModel:**

```
public class GenreViewModel
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(Genre), GenreId); } }

    public static List<GenreViewModel> AllGenres
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Genre)).Cast<Genre>().Select(v => new GenreViewModel
            {
                GenreId = ((int)v)
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllGenres))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Muecke gave the answer in the comments.(don't know how to choose his comment as an answer correctly)

```
dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.AllGenres)).
```

but I did not declare a model in my view, so
I used my static property:

```
dataSource: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Number2.Models.GenreViewModel.GetAllGenres))
```